# React get element from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on app which displays products from an API and I want to update the product count onClick.

```
const changeProductCount = async (code) => {
  let modifiedFilters = filters;
  modifiedFilters.sellingFilters = code;
  await getContent(modifiedFilters);
};
```

It works but I realized that the key I need is the "code" key within the filters array, not the one at the top of the sellingAidsFilters array.

```
sellingFilters: Array(1)

0:

code: "SRULEG2189"

filters: Array(2)

    0: {priority: 0, code: "SRULE4660", name: "Modern", image: "000dfb61-ab65-4100-9080 
    37a70e29c369", productCount: 370}

    1: {priority: 1, code: "SRULE4663", name: "Classic", image: "f3757d1c-f7d8-4776-813c- 
    5af32a2e7fee", productCount: 0}
```

I tried to use `.find` to retrieve the key but it returns an error of undefined:

```
const changeProductCount = async (code) => {
  let modifiedFilters = filters;
  modifiedFilters.sellingFilters[0].filters.find((element) => element.code).code) = code;
  await getContent(modifiedFilters);
};
```

How can I extract the code key from the array to use in my function? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you need to update 1 item in array or you need to find some item in array and  then update it and pass it to function ?

Comment: I need to update 1 item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const newFilters = filters.map(item => item.code === code ? {...item, keyToUpdate: valueToUpdate} : item);
```